# Extract lowest MSEP from Principal Component Regression in R

Tags: r

I would like to extract the lowest MSEP from a Principal Components Regression. In the example below, I would like to add a line of code that will cat a line saying "Best MSE of [x] was produced with [y] components," where [x] is the minimum CV MSE (not adjusted CV) in MSEP_object, and [y] is the number of components that produce that MSE.

```
library(MASS)
library(pls)
PCR_fit <- pcr(crim~., data=Boston, scale=TRUE, validation="CV")
MSEP_object <- MSEP(PCR_fit)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at:

```
str(MSEP_object)
#------
List of 5
 $ val       : num [1:2, 1, 1:14] 74.1 74.1 51.8 51.8 51.8 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 3
  .. ..$ estimate: chr [1:2] "CV" "adjCV"
  .. ..$ response: chr "crim"
  .. ..$ model   : chr [1:14] "(Intercept)" "1 comps" "2 comps" "3 comps" ...
 $ type      : chr "MSEP"
 $ comps     : num [1:14] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
 $ cumulative: logi TRUE
 $ call      : language MSEP.mvr(object = PCR_fit)
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "mvrVal"
```

It pretty easy to see that the "CV"-row is the first dimension of the array accessed by `MSEP_object$val`.

```
> MSEP_object$val[1,1, ]
(Intercept)     1 comps     2 comps     3 comps     4 comps     5 comps     6 comps 
   74.13309    51.81121    51.77481    45.79611    45.60764    45.84421    46.42630 
    7 comps     8 comps     9 comps    10 comps    11 comps    12 comps    13 comps 
   46.32160    44.53877    44.83946    45.02798    44.91884    44.49455    43.51062 
> which.min(MSEP_object$val[1,1, ] )
13 comps 
      14
```

I would refrain from calling it the "best" since that implies some sort of statistical judgment but would rather suggest:

```
  paste( "Minimum MSE of ",  
         MSEP_object$val[1,1, ][ which.min(MSEP_object$val[1,1, ] )], 
         " was produced with ", 
         sub(" comps","", names(which.min(MSEP_object$val[1,1, ] ))), 
         " components")
 #[1] "Minimum MSE of  43.51061955445  was produced with  13  components"
```